# Capture, save and retrieve images/pictures using Sqlite

Tags: xamarin.android

How to save the image from imageview to the sqlite database, and retrieve it again to an Imgeview?

[full code not work url](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fgnEdjJvikfLo-F_-JsaNjRpNDOp9tu5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, you want to save ImageView image into Sqlite database and load image from Sqlite database into ImageView, am I right?

If yes, firstly, you need to create class to load image:

```
public class Image
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then installing **sqlite-net-pcl** to connect Sqlite database.

Finally, you may need to consider to convert imageview image into byte[] to save, and converting byte[] to bitmp to load in imageview.

Please take a look the full code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/a11"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:text="insert image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button android:id="@+id/button2" 
    android:text="display image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button3" 
    android:text="create table"/>
</LinearLayout>

 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    private ImageView imageview1;
    private ImageView imageview2;

    private byte[] insertbitmapData;

    private Button btninsert;
    private Button btnload;
    private Button btntable;

    private SQLiteConnection _SQLiteConnection;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);


        btninsert = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
        btninsert.Click += Btninsert_Click;
        btnload = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button2);
        btnload.Click += Btnload_Click;
        btntable = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button3);
        btntable.Click += Btntable_Click;
        imageview1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
        imageview2 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView2);

    }

    private void Btnload_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string filename = "test";
        var imagedata = _SQLiteConnection.Table<Image>();
        var d1 = imagedata.Where(x => x.FileName == filename).FirstOrDefault();
        if(d1!=null)
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = d1.Content;             
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(ms);
                imageview2.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);

            }

        }
    }

    private void Btninsert_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = ((BitmapDrawable)imageview1.Drawable).Bitmap;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
            insertbitmapData = stream.ToArray();
        }
        Image image = new Image();
        image.FileName = "test";
        image.Content = insertbitmapData;

        var imagedata = _SQLiteConnection.Table<Image>();

        var d1 = imagedata.Where(x => x.FileName == image.FileName).FirstOrDefault();
        if (d1 == null)
        {
            _SQLiteConnection.Insert(d1);
            Console.WriteLine("Sucessfully Added");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Already image id Exist");
        }            
    }

    private void Btntable_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        createsqlite();
    }

    private void createsqlite()
    {
        var fileName = "imagedata.db3";
        var documentPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(documentPath, fileName);

        _SQLiteConnection = new SQLiteConnection(path);
        _SQLiteConnection.CreateTable<Image>();
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

public class Image
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

The sample at github:

https://github.com/CherryBu/InsertImage

**Update:**

```
public class User
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: hi cherry  When you click on the Restore and Upload Image button from the database, nothing appears

Comment: @maher2020 Firstly, you need to create one sqlite database by clicking Create table Button, then clicking Button1 to insert imageview image into sqlite database, finally, you can get image from sqlite database into imageview2 by clicking Button2.

Comment: hi cherry , Thank you for following up . I don't think I have missed the work steps, which is creating a table, entering data and displaying data. I made some changes with the link  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Rnx7hRxnROrGmOWZDZl7Vr1DAmeCw39w    . The problem remains

Comment: @maher2020 Now I can reproduce your problem when test my my code, but it works fine yesterday, so I suggest you can create new class and create new table to try again. Take a look my update.